# Dokan (DokanNet.dll) on Android/Monodroid - Code Migration Issue

Tags: android, filesystems, xamarin.android, dokan

**Context:** 
I have an windows desktop app(c#) which loads the dokan libraries , creates a new file system/drive each time it runs, and then deploys financial data files & copywrite protected files in the newly created drive - Allowing only limited process (declared by me) to have access to these files in newly created file system(using  dokan).
Now we are migrating the same C# code to android. Though the code doesn’t give Errors, (while running apk)the new drive is not created. While i could debug only to an extent (suddenly get out of debugging mode)

**Assumptions for the issue:** 
Permission issues:

**Question:**

Does Dokan work with Android? How to go about this, if it’s a permission issue? In market place, most of the devices installing my app may not be "rooted"!!
Has anyone implemented new file system/drive using DokanNet on Android/Monodroid and faced with similar issues? Solutions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a tool it's a good idea to have some basic understanding of how it works. Dokan works by installing Windows filesystem driver. On Android there's no concept of drives and mounting anything to the filesystem is not possible (without building custom kernel and installing it on device). Consequently your idea is DOA on Android and you need to look for other ways to deal with your data.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, could you please suggest me any work arnd ideas frm ur experience. Iam Kind of stuck here.

Comment: @Ant-Roid As I mentioned, on Android (as well as other smartphone platforms) it's not possible to create some globally-visible virtual storage (like a virtual disk on Windows). Platforms just don't offer such capabilities.

Comment: "Platforms just don't offer such capabilities." That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Eugene, Iam not depending only on the idea of creating a "Virtual drive" to protect visibility/existence of the content file from the user. There should be some other way to "provide the file access for some processess only and at the same time give protection/invisiblity on mount level". Some thing like a file on private mode on internal storage.(dont want to use internal storage in this case).

Comment: @RobertHensing I was referring to smartphone platforms.

Comment: @Ant-Roid what makes you think that it should?

Comment: @Eugene, There is two parts to where my app is storing data, Locally in protected Archeive and other online. Online to app data load will take time, so most of the historical data is coming from Local. But we are making the user think that every data He/she is getting is from online db. Only when new analytical data changes happen, i sync it with local.(Its financial data and the system can be used by many people(who many not be the intented)). Hence i want to keep the existence of this files in local away from normal users and other applications.

Comment: @Ant-Droid The solution depends on how the user gets the data - does some third-party application open files on the disk or uses some API. In your case "opens files on the disk" is the problem which can not be solved on smartphones, so you have to redesign this part.